# Making a combo box readonly

Tags: c++, combobox, dialog

I created a combobox from the resource for a dialog box in c++ and am trying to make it readonly. I have tried this but it's not working

```
LONG style = GetWindowLong(hWndComboBox, GWL_STYLE);
style |= CBS_DROPDOWNLIST;
SetWindowLong(hWndComboBox, GWL_STYLE, style);
```

I also tried this but didn't work too

```
SendMessage(hWndComboBox, BM_SETSTYLE, CBS_DROPDOWNLIST, 0);
```

though I have a feeling it shouldn't be `BM_SETSTYLE`